# Need help in understanding how two linear transformations are the same in Linear Algebra.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, proof-explanation, linear-transformations

I was studying the book Linear Algebra by Stephen H Friedberg, Insel and Spence. I was reading about Invertibility and Isomorphism from section 2.4 in Chapter 2 of the book.

There was a point where I seem to be stuck as I am not quite understanding how a particular claim was established by "reformulating" a previous theorem which mentioned in the book.

I will post the portion explicitly in here. But before that, I will specify some definitions for reference (**which may be an optional read**):

- Let $β$ be an ordered basis for an $n-$dimensional vector space $V$ over the field $F.$ The standard representation of $V$ with respect to
  $β$ is the function $φ_β : V → F^n$ defined by $φ_β(x)=[x]_β$ for each $x ∈ V$ (, where $[x]_β$ is the coordinate vector of $x$ with respect to the ordered basis $\beta$ of $V.$).
- Let $A$ be an $m × n$ matrix with entries from a field $F.$ We denote by $L_A$ the mapping $L_A : F^n → F^m$ defined by $L_A(x) = Ax$ (the matrix product of $A$ and $x$) for each column vector $x ∈ F^n.$ We call $L_A$ a left-multiplication transformation.

---

The part where I am stuck is as follows:

[image]

Let $V$ and $W$ be vector spaces of dimension $n$ and $m,$ respectively, and let $T: V → W$ be a linear transformation. Define $A = [T]^γ_β,$ where $β$ and $γ$ are arbitrary ordered bases of $V$ and $W,$ respectively. We are now able to use $φ_β$ and $φ_γ$ to study the relationship between the linear transformations $T$ and
$L_A : F^n → F^m.$

Let us first consider Figure 2.2. Notice that there are two composites of linear transformations that map $V$ into $F^m:$

1. Map $V$ into $F^n$ with $φ_β$ and follow this transformation with $L_A;$ this yields the composite $L_Aφ_β.$
2. Map $V$ into $W$ with $T$ and follow it by $φ_γ$ to obtain the composite $φ_γT.$

These two composites are depicted by the dashed arrows in the diagram.
By a simple reformulation of Theorem $2.14$ (p. $91$)

(The theorem is:

Let $V$ and $W$ be finite-dimensional vector spaces having ordered bases $β$ and $γ,$ respectively, and let $T: V → W$ be linear. Then, for each $u ∈ V,$ we have $[T(u)]_γ = [T]^γ_β[u]_β$)

,we may conclude that $L_Aφ_β = φ_γT;$ that is, the diagram “commutes.”

---

However, I don't get at all, how do they write,

> By a simple reformulation of Theorem $2.14$ (p. $91$), we may conclude that $L_Aφ_β = φ_γT;$ that is, the diagram “commutes.”

I don't get how to reformulate that theorem in order to arrive at the conclusion, $L_Aφ_β = φ_γT.$  All in all, I don't get how to conclude $L_Aφ_β = φ_γT$ *without* using the theorem as well. Any help regarding tjis will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: by definition you have that $[T]_\beta^\gamma v=(\phi_\gamma \circ T\circ \phi^{-1}_\beta)v$ for any $v\in F^n$, hence the result

Comment: @Masacroso Sorry, but unfortunately, I never came accross the definition you mention. Mind providing some additional context?

Comment: then what is your definition of $[T]_\beta^\gamma$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're maybe getting tripped up by the word "reformulation".

Starting with $u\in V$ in the upper left corner of the diagram, if you first go vertically down by applying $\phi_{\beta}$, you get $[u]_{\beta}$, and then if you go horizontally across by applying $L_A$, where $A=[T]_{\beta}^{\gamma}$, you get $[T]_{\beta}^{\gamma}[u]_{\beta}$.

On the other hand if you first go horizontally across by applying $T$, you get $T(u)$, and then if you go vertically down by applying $\phi_{\gamma}$, you get $[T(u)]_{\gamma}$.

Commutativity of the diagram just means by definition that these two resulting things are always the same, that is $[T(u)]_{\gamma}=[T]_{\beta}^{\gamma}[u]_{\beta}$, which is precisely what the theorem says. In other words, the theorem tells you that the diagram commutes.

Comment: Thanks a ton! +1 from me. I think you don't mind as I edited your answer by changing "$Tu$ " to the usual notation $T(u)$ ?

Comment: @ThomasFinley $Tu$ is the usual notation, at least outside of introductory texts. Writing the brackets becomes extremely tiresome once you start composing lots of mappings.

Answer (score 2):

I think $L_A$ takes coordinates to coordinates while $T$ is a linear transformation. Also by definition $A = [T]_\alpha^{\beta}$ is a matrix. Now if $x \in V$ you can get the coordinates of the transformed vector by performing $L_A (\varphi_\alpha(x))$ or by first applying $T$ and then retrieving the coordinates $\varphi_\beta(T(x))$ both they will give you the same result for any $x \in V$. Therefore

$$
\forall x \in V \;\; L_A (\varphi_\alpha(x)) = \varphi_\beta(T(x)) \iff \forall x \in V \;\; \left(L_A \circ \varphi_\alpha\right)(x) = \left(\varphi_\beta \circ T \right)(x) \iff \\ \forall x \in V \;\; \left(L_A \circ \varphi_\alpha\right)(x) - \left(\varphi_\beta \circ T \right)(x) = 0 \iff \forall x \in V \;\; \left(L_A \circ \varphi_\alpha - \varphi_\beta \circ T \right)(x) = 0 \iff L_A \circ \varphi_\alpha - \varphi_\beta \circ T = 0 \iff L_A \circ \varphi_\alpha = \varphi_\beta \circ T
$$

Which is your conclusion.

**Update:** I hope you understand my notation, otherwise we can open a chat. If $T : V \to W$ and $\left\{ v_\alpha \right\}$ is a basis of $V$ and $\left\{ w_\beta \right\}$ is a basis then $T$ can be described by a matrix. Let $v \in V$, we have $v = \sum_{\alpha} c_{\alpha}v_{\alpha}$, $c_\alpha \in F$. Let's calculate $Tv$

$$
Tv = T \left( \sum_{\alpha} c_{\alpha}v_{\alpha} \right) =  \sum_{\alpha} c_{\alpha} T v_{\alpha}
$$

But each $Tv_{\alpha}$ can be expressed in the basis $\left\{w_{\beta}\right\}$, leading to

$$
Tv_{\alpha} = \sum_{\beta} [T]_{\alpha}^{\beta} w_{\beta}
$$

Substituting this back gives us

$$
Tv = \sum_{\alpha}\sum_{\beta} [T]_{\alpha}^{\beta} w_{\beta}
$$

But $Tv$ on its own can be represented w.r.t the basis $\left\{ w_{\beta} \right\}$

$$
Tv = \sum_{\beta} b_\beta w_{\beta}.
$$

Combining everything together

$$
\sum_{\beta} b_\beta w_{\beta} = \sum_{\alpha}\sum_{\beta} [T]_{\alpha}^{\beta} w_{\beta} \iff b_\beta = \sum_{\alpha} [T]_{\alpha}^{\beta} c_{\alpha}.
$$

In the last equation you have coordinate transformations. And we know how each coordinates are related to the actual vector.

$$
b_{\beta} = \varphi_{\beta}(Tv) = (\varphi_{\beta} \circ T)(v)
$$

While the right handside is equivalent to get $c_{\alpha} = \varphi_{\alpha}(v)$ and then applying $L_A$ where $A$ is the matrix defined in your post or in my calculations.

Then apply everything I did before this update and you get the commutativity.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But I have a question. In your answer, you wrote,  "Now if $x \in V$ you can get the coordinates of the transformed vector by performing $L_A (\varphi_\alpha(x))$ or by first applying $T$ and then retrieving the coordinates $\varphi_\beta(T(x))$ both they will give you the same result for any $x \in V$." But I don't get this statement.

Comment: I've updated my answer, but I think my notation is different from yours. If you don't get it we can discuss further.